# Kendo UI Popup Grid Editor without a grid

Tags: kendo-ui, popup

I am using Kendo UI for ASP.MVC.  I currently have a grid setup and working for the standard crud operations.  What I would like is to be able to invoke the editor from a link click outside of the grid.  Is something like this possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific ? By saying link out side the grid do you mean you will be having links for each rows in the page outside the grid ?

Comment: Let's say I have a grid to show a list of objects.  I can edit one of the objects using the grid's add/edit functionality.  The Add/Edit mode for the grid is a popup, so I have a view on the editortemplates folder.  Now let's say I am viewing a details page for a specific item from the grid.  I want to be able to bring up the same edit popup on the details page that I used on the grid page.  It seems as though this should be possible.  I am using the .NET MVC code, but if I have to do it through javascript that would be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

*editRow* can be ur answer see 
[Doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-editRow) and
[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IsiJO)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  The page I am trying to invoke the editor on won't have a grid at all.

Comment: @Nick grid popup editor is rendered on the same page with grid so you should not have problem calling **editRow**